# Format JSON data - Nesting

Tags: json

I have the following JSON, which is sample data:

```
{
    "aaData": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "guid": "cb9f9f60-0257-421a-885a-42e7a38c8f16",
            "detail": {
                "datetime": "1993-11-18T19:58:10 -00:00",
                "info": [
                    "fugiat",
                    "ad",
                    "Lorem",
                    "nisi",
                    "occaecat",
                    "incididunt",
                    "nostrud"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The data is a row of data, I want to add another set of data to the JSON so that I can also store the column names in the same file.

Can anyone help me modify this JSON to include another object to store the column names?

Comment: Are the column names not the same as the keys you're already using? If so, then you can access the column names by accessing the key names and not need another set of data. If not, can you go into more detail about the data structure you want to represent as JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON is really pretty easy once you know the basics, and it's difficult to understand what you're trying to say in words, so I'll see if I can't break it down for you. [Douglas Crockford](http://www.crockford.com/) is *the* source for JSON, and [his website](http://www.json.org/) makes it fairly easy to understand the syntax.

When trying to sculpt your JSON, I highly recommend validating your JSON against some online service like [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/) or [jslint.com](http://www.jslint.com/).

Your question could be interpreted in multiple ways. One way might say that you want to have the array `aaData` contain multiple objects. Here is how you would do that:

```
{
    "aaData": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "guid": "cb9f9f60-0257-421a-885a-42e7a38c8f16",
            "detail": {
                "datetime": "1993-11-18T19:58:10 -00:00",
                "info": [
                    "fugiat",
                    "ad",
                    "Lorem",
                    "nisi",
                    "occaecat",
                    "incididunt",
                    "nostrud"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "guid": "cb9f9f60-0257-421a-885a-42e7a38c8f17",
            "detail": {
                "datetime": "1993-11-19T19:58:10 -00:00",
                "info": [
                    "fugiata",
                    "ad",
                    "Lorem",
                    "nisi",
                    "occaecat",
                    "incididunt",
                    "nostrud"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Another way to interpret it is that you want to have another object beside `aaData` which contains some information about the objects inside the `aaData` array. You would need to groom the columns and objects to ensure they maintain a one-to-one relationship, but here's how you would do it:

```
{
    "aaData": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "guid": "cb9f9f60-0257-421a-885a-42e7a38c8f16",
            "detail": {
                "datetime": "1993-11-18T19:58:10 -00:00",
                "info": [
                    "fugiat",
                    "ad",
                    "Lorem",
                    "nisi",
                    "occaecat",
                    "incididunt",
                    "nostrud"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "guid": "cb9f9f60-0257-421a-885a-42e7a38c8f17",
            "detail": {
                "datetime": "1993-11-19T19:58:10 -00:00",
                "info": [
                    "fugiata",
                    "ad",
                    "Lorem",
                    "nisi",
                    "occaecat",
                    "incididunt",
                    "nostrud"
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "columns": [
        {
            "meta": 1
        },
        {
            "meta": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your comment, lesson learned - will try harder.